# Ruby on Rails Serialize hash object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, serialization

how can I serialize this hash to this string in Ruby on Rails?

Thanks!

```
{"options"=>{"first_name"=>"Jeremy", "favorite_beer"=>"Bells Hopslam"}} =>
"{'options[favorite_beer]': 'Bells Hopslam', 'options[first_name]': 'Jeremy'}"
```

Comment: Why do you want this? It seems like you're trying to do something fishy without providing all of the details, and usually there's a better way to accomplish whatever you're trying to do

Comment: i have to load mercury snippets like this: `Mercury.Snippet.load({
          snippet_1: {name: 'example', options: {'options[favorite_beer]': "Bells Hopslam", 'options[first_name]': "Jeremy"}}
        });` and have a serialized object of options available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not completely assured that you're doing the right thing here, but to just answer your question:

```
def stringify(hash)
  items = hash.map do |key, inner|
    inner.map { |k, v| "'#{key}[#{k}]': '#{v}'" }
  end

  "{#{items.join(', ')}}"
end


p stringify({"options"=>{"first_name"=>"Jeremy", "favorite_beer"=>"Bells Hopslam"}})
#=> "{'options[first_name]': 'Jeremy', 'options[favorite_beer]': 'Bells Hopslam'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also serialize it in YAML or JSON.

```
{"options"=>{"first_name"=>"Jeremy", "favorite_beer"=>"Bells Hopslam"}}.to_yaml =>

"--- \noptions: \n  first_name: Jeremy\n  favorite_beer: Bells Hopslam\n"
```

or

```
{"options"=>{"first_name"=>"Jeremy", "favorite_beer"=>"Bells Hopslam"}}.to_json =>

"{\"options\":{\"first_name\":\"Jeremy\",\"favorite_beer\":\"Bells Hopslam\"}}"
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't see it was particularly for Mercury. Yeah, you'll have to use a custom method.